# Best way to implement cart on an ecommerce reactjs webapp

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I was using react-redux/redux-persist to persist the cart data but whenever I tried to update and reload my webpage the cart returns to the version of data it was since persisted.

Comment: Are you dispatching the update action?

Comment: How does that work

Comment: Can you send link for the repo?

Comment: As @ErickWachira says, if you dispatch the action and save it into the store, you shouldt lose any data.

Answer (score 2):

When you refresh the page redux data will be cleared.